# Env variables placeholder

Tags: next.js, deployment, dockerfile, devops, .env

i have a question regarding something , so i have such an .env:

```
.env 

secret = ${secret}
id=${id}
```

And i need to use the env with placeholders , something like above because i deploy this app to kubernetes and there i have in values.yaml the env details that i need.

The question is how to set these values in .env because i do not want them hardcoded, maybe using docker or something like this.

The app is very simple just a nextjs application:

```
const { ID,SECRET } = process.env;
```

I tried maybe using env from dockerfile but nextjs want the .env only type file.
Any ideas how to handle this?